# Array by value multiplication memory leak in c++

Tags: c++11

I'm having some trouble with multiplying an array (char array in this particular case) by a value.
My code looks like this:

```
char* tab1 = copy("11");
char t = '2';
int length = strlen(tab1) + 2;
char*result = populate('0', length);
int p_length = strlen(tab1);
for (int j = p_length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    char* tmp = multiply_chars(tab1[j], t);
    v_shove(tmp, j);
    char* tmp2 = add_tables(result, tmp);
    delete[] result;
    result = tmp2;
    delete[] tmp;
}
cout << result << endl;
delete[] result;
delete[] tab1;
```

None of the methods used (that's populate, multiply_chars and add_tables) causes a leak when ran in an infinite loop. I've narrowed the leak to the

```
char* tmp2 = add_tables(result, tmp);
delete[] result;
result = tmp2;
```

part, but have no idea why it would happen.
I check for leaks by running snippets in an infinite loop and checking memory usage.
Any help would be appreciated! If need be I'll post the code of the methods used, but decided not to for the sake of brevity here. They all return new cstrings. Also, the t2 variable is there from when I was checking the array by array multiplication, which also leaked - decided to do array by value multiplication first.
(Now, to be completely honest this is one of the methods required for a school project, but it's such a miniscule part of it, that I thought it wouldn't hurt if I asked - the teacher isn't really big on helping with particular code problems)

The functions are:

```
char * add_tables(const char * table1, const char * table2)
{
    char* tmp1 = get_string_trailing("0",table1);
    char* tmp2 = get_string_trailing("0", table2);
    int l1 = strlen(tmp1), l2 = strlen(tmp2);
    if (l1 != l2) {
        if (l1 > l2) {
            char* t = resize_string(tmp2, l1 - l2, '0');
            delete[] tmp2;
            tmp2 = t;
        }
        else {
            char* t = resize_string(tmp1, l2 - l1, '0');
            delete[] tmp1;
            tmp1 = t;
        }
}
    int length = strlen(tmp1) + 2;
    char*result = new char[length];
    result[length - 1] = 0;
    int buffer = 0;
    for (int i = length - 2; i > 0; i--) {
        int t = buffer + (tmp1[i-1]-'0') + (tmp2[i-1]-'0');
        result[i] = (t% 10)+'0';
        buffer = (t - (t % 10))/10;
    }
    result[0] = buffer + '0';
    char* t = get_string_trailing("0", result);
    delete[]result;
    result = t;
    delete[]tmp1;
    delete[]tmp2;
    return result;
}
void v_shove(char *&c, int i)
{
    char* tmp = shove(c, i);
    delete[] c;
    c = tmp;
}
char * populate(const char populator, int length)
{
    char* result = new char[length + 1];
    result[length] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = populator;
    }
    return result;
}
char * multiply_chars(const char c1,const char c2)
{
    char*result = new char[3];
    result[2] = 0;
    char tmp1 = c1 - '0', tmp2 = c2 - '0';
    result[1] = (tmp1*tmp2 % 10) + '0';
    result[0] = (tmp1*tmp2 - (tmp1*tmp2 % 10)) / 10 + '0';
    char* r = get_string_trailing("0", result);
    delete[] result;
    result = r;
    return result;
}
int get_length_trailing(const char * ignore,const char * table)
{
    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    bool flag = true;
    while (i < strlen(table)) {
        if (flag) {
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ignore); j++)
            if (table[i] == ignore[j])goto BREAKPOINT;
        }
        flag = false;
        length++;
    BREAKPOINT:i++;
    }
    return length;
}
char * get_string_trailing(const char * ignore,const char * table)
{
    int result_length = get_length_trailing(ignore, table);
    char* result = new char[result_length + 1];
    int counter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    bool flag = true;
    while (i < strlen(table)) {
        if (flag)
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ignore); j++)
                if (table[i] == ignore[j])goto BREAKPOINT;
        flag = false;
        result[counter] = table[i];
        counter++;
    BREAKPOINT:i++;
    }
    result[result_length] = 0;
    if (result_length == 0) return copy("0");
    return result;
}
char * shove(const char * table1, int index)
{
    char*result = "0";
    int length = strlen(table1) + index + 1;
    result = new char[length];
    result[length - 1] = 0;
    if (index > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(table1); i++)
            result[i] = table1[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            result[strlen(table1) + i] = '0';
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(result); i++)
            result[i] = table1[i];
    }
    char* t = get_string_trailing("0", result);
    delete[] result;
    result = t;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Without that it's going to be impossible to help you. Also, if you have a memory debugger (like e.g. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)) then *use* it, and if you don't then get one.

Comment: Also, how do you *know* you have a memory leak? How do you check it now? *Seems* to cause a leak is pretty vague.

Comment: Yes, sir, I think this is, unfortunately, the most minimal snippet I can post with all the required functions added. I'm very sorry if it's unreadable - I'm still a beginner and this is truly boggling my mind.
I check for leaks by looking at the memory usage in visual studio - I run an infinite while loop and look at the usage chart.
I ran into the issue while I was making a factorial function, a test for 1221 factorial crashed due to the stack overflow, so I've been plugging leaks yesterday, and this is the only one left.

Comment: If you're programming in C++, why aren't you using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? The standard string class in C++. Then you don't have to do *any* manual memory handling, and don't have to worry about memory leaks or many other things usually going wrong with pointers.

Comment: Lastly, if your program is so complex that you can't show it all here, then it's probably a good idea to start over. Make a good design (or *any* design really) on paper first before you try to write code. And then only implement the design piece by piece, one little bit at a time, verifying that it works (and have no leaks) before going on to the next part. Also think about things like variable naming and commenting, you're not the only one who is going to read the code after all. In the end you should have a nice program that you should be proud of.

Comment: Well, I assumed that this would be the best way to go about it, having access to any char from the cstring. We are supposed to make a typical BigNum class with all the operations required.
As I mentioned, I'm still very new to C++, memory handling wasn't an issue in Java, so now I run into issues like this one a lot.
Should I switch to std::string then? I haven't used it before at all.

Comment: @skogarr first thing to unlearn from Java is using `new`. In Java `new` means "Create an object". In c++ `new` means "Manually allocate unmanaged memory that I promise to take care of myself, and create an object there". You don't want to take care of memory yourself if you don't know how to do that. Even if you do, you don't want to take care of it if you don't have to. And you don't have to, because there is `std::string`, `std::vector` etc.

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen!
Some programmer dude, I've taken your advice and am rewriting the whole project (I had the algorithms designed, it was just a matter of mistranslating them into c++),
user(numbers) - that actually clears things up a bit for me
Appreciate you taking the time, thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least a memory leak in `get_string_trailing`: if `result_length` is zero, you return a copy and do not delete `result`. There are also confusions between `"string"` (such as `"0"`) and `'char'`: with double quotes, the terminating string character (`\0`) is automatically appended to the string, while simple quotes only define a character. So `"0"` is made of 2 `char` in memory and can not be stored in a pointer (undefined behavior, overwriting memory).

To summarize: here you are writing C, not learning C++. If you have to deal with C strings (you are writing a low-level pilot in C or your professor still doesn't understand that C and C++ are different languages), at least use the functions of the `string.h` (in C) / `cstring` (in C++) header to minimize the chance of memory leak or undefined behavior. If you do not have to use C strings, use `std::string` and the string manipulation tools of the standard library. Your work will be much easier, and your code much less vulnerable to bugs:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string tab1("11")
  string t("2") // never use the single quotes for a string
  cout << stoi(tab1) * stoi(t) << endl;
  return;
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you sir! This actually seems to have fixed my issue - I've taken Some programmer dude's advice to rewrite it as strings, but your answer pointed out another mistake that I wouldn't have noticed.
I appreciate you taking the time, thank you again!